# SQL Plus window does not retain all lines of query and output

Tags: windows, oracle, cmd, command-line-interface, sqlplus

My SQL Plus window does not retain all the lines of output/input.

After a clear screen, I ran the following queries in the EMP table from "scott/tiger" in order:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY EMPNO;
SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY EMPNO;
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE COMM IS NOT NULL;
```

I should be getting the whole table with 14 rows twice and then an output of 4 rows for the last query. Instead, I can scroll back up to only EMPNO 7654 from the first query. This is causing problems when working with larger tables as the whole output is not fitted in the window.

[This is the farthest I can scroll up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guBHb.png)

How do I get it show all the output from the start of the session?
Or, at least, significantly increase the amount of lines shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's Windows CMD , so you just need to open CMD settings (right click on header) and change buffer settings. For example I usually increase it up to 3000 lines.
If it is not WIndows cmd window, try to start cmd window first, change buffer settings and then start sqlplus in that window

Comment: Going in the Defaults option, I have a Command History section under the Options tab. There I have values for Buffer Size and Number of Buffers. Which one did you increase?

Comment: @tukykarmakar open Layout tab and change buffer settings

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer showed how to increase the buffer of the command window, and thus how far back you could scroll.  But there quickly comes a point where it is not really practical to scroll back some massive amount. My answer would be to use the sqlplus 'spool' command if you really want to capture the entire session.  This will capture everything to a text file that you can review even after your session is terminated and the window closed.  You can read about the spool command in the *[SQL Plus User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqpug/index.html)*.